# Is it possible to be accurate when Users are created within OSX?

Tags: macos

I am trying to prove creation dates when users were created on a Mac OSX computer. Some dates go back to 2009 (which would be when the computer was first used) and some overlap in 2012.

I also have two user accounts: `John` and `Johnnew_user`

Does this indicate that the original was deleted and a new User account created that overwrote the original?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing computer forensics and want to use this information in court this two-letter word gives you the answer:

## NO!

Unless a strong certified security mechanism is put in place no one can prove nobody else hacked the computer, mounted the HDD on a separate machine and messed up with files containing dates. Only if files were timestamped by third-party authority you would gain proof benefit.

The fact that you have accounts named like that doesn't prove anything, at least if somebody *wants* you to believe an account was deleted.

It doesn't prove but suggests that somebody couldn't create another account named `John` and named his new account `Johnnew_user`